Is there a way to control how WPF windows act when executed from another WPF App?
I've created a WPF APP (.NET Framework) that acts as a Launcher for other applications existing in the same directory as the Launcher. When I launch most of the apps this do not appear in the foreground, I can see the Icon in the taskbar pop up with that orange shine to it like a newly opened app ussually has but it opens in the background. On top of that when this launched app has other windows or prompts and I close one of them, it does not show me the "parent" window but instead focuses on the last thing i opened before launching that app, for example Chrome.
Im Launching my apps this way:
private void TextBlock_Click(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is TextBlock textBlock)
    {
        string appName = textBlock.Text.Replace(" ", "");
        string executablePath = $"{appName}.exe";

        if (File.Exists(executablePath))
        {
            if (!IsApplicationRunning(appName))
            {
                string arguments = appName == "GestioneSpedizioni" ? "S RESP" : string.Empty;

                var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
                {
                    FileName = executablePath,
                    Arguments = arguments,
                };

                Process.Start(startInfo);
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show($"L'applicazione '{appName}' è già in esecuzione.");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Errore: il file non si trova nel percorso specificato");
        }
    }
}

